# Minkowski inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$  be two sequences of integers and $\lambda\in \Bbb N$. Clearly by Minkowski inequality we get
$$(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i-b_i|^2)^\frac12\geq (\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|^2)^\frac12 - (\sum_{i=1}^\infty |b_i|^2)^\frac12.$$
In a Paper I saw the following inequality
$$(\lambda + \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i-b_i|^2)^\frac12\geq (\lambda+\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|^2)^\frac12 - (\sum_{i=1}^\infty |b_i|^2)^\frac12.$$
Could someone prove this inequality? Infact, I need to know why this inequality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the first formula for the modified sequences
 $$a'=(\sqrt\lambda,\  a_1,a_2,a_3, \dots) \\
b'=(0,\ b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots)$$